# Push notifications not being sent from parse-server to iOS devices

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using parse-server to send push notifications to my app. When I manually send push notifications from it, iOS devices won't receive them. It works fine in Android though.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is it Parse Server's issue or anything else?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you uploaded the certs and registered for remote notifications in each device ?

Comment: @nathan, Yes I've uploaded certs: https://dotjpg.co/Kr6FWV.png

Comment: Have you confirmed push sents in your app dashboard of Parse?Have you tried to send push on specific device target? Does your app registering token successfully with parse?

Comment: @Ellen, I can see successfully sent pushes: https://dotjpg.co/v3Gb.png
I've tried for all devices. It worked in all Android devices, but didn't receive to any iOS. App is registered with parse too.

Comment: Ok.. it seems to be an issue from Parse server. Have you tried once with Distribution certificate? Because the biggest reasons for push issue can only be either app token registration or certificates.

Comment: @Ellen, I'll try with Distribution certificate. Thank you.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, you should activate VERBOSE mode and paste the log output